# Как оправить форму методом POST

Tags: php, html

У меня есть форма, вот она:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" method="post" action="upd.php" class="form-control" placeholder="Номер телефона">
<input type="text" name="comment" method="post" action="upd.php" class="form-control" placeholder="Что изменить">
<button type="submit" name="btn-send" formmethod="post" formaction="upd.php" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success mb-3">Отправить</button>
```

Как мне сделать эту форму рабочей?

Comment: Разделим этот вопрс на два. Для начала научимся отправлять формы. А потом уже, без всякой связи с формами, будем учиться выполнять запросы к БД

Comment: у вас нет формы

Comment: @Ипатьев да, спасибо, форма отправилась, запрос к бд был корректный

Comment: запросу к БД до корректности как отсюда до Юпитера. В чем тебе еще предстоит неприятно убедиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обернуть всё это в тег `<form>` с указанием типа запроса `POST` конечно жи

```html
<form type="post" action="upd.php">
    <input ...>
    <input ...>
    <button ...>Кнопка</button>
</form>
```

В самих инпутах атрибуты `method` и `action` браузером не обрабатываются

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы прилепили кучу не нужных аттрибутов к тегам (их даже для них не существует).

```html
<form action="site.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputText">Text</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputText" id="inputText" aria-describedby="helpId"
      placeholder="text">
    <small id="helpId">Help text</small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```